# Functional Programming in Java 8

Tags: interface, java-8, functional-programming

As for as I have understood that functional Programming means to give a different behavor implementations interface. Would that be better than I had to create a new Class and implemented that interface in it?
I am not clear on this

```
interface worldGreeting {
 String processName(String str);
}
public class ReadJson {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    worldGreeting morningGreeting = (str) -> "Good Morning " + str + "!";
    worldGreeting eveningGreeting = (str) -> "Good Evening " + str + "!";
    System.out.println(morningGreeting.processName("Waseem"));
    System.out.println(eveningGreeting.processName("Saeed"));
}

}
```

Second approach would be like this

```
class Moring implements worldGreeting{
@Override
public String processName(String str) {
    return "Good Morning " + str + "!";
  }
  }

 class Evening implements worldGreeting{

@Override
public String processName(String str) {
    return "Good Evening " + str + "!";
  }
 }
```

Comment: SAM types are an ugly hack.

Comment: You should rethink your naming. The convention is to let types, including interfaces, start with an uppercase. Further, don’t call a class `ReadJson` when it doesn’t have anything to do with reading Json. Besides that, functional programming is not about how you implement an interface. But you should be able to see the obvious advantage of using a lambda expressions in your example…

Comment: The only advantage in your case is that with lambda you don't have to create explicit classes or anonymous classes that implement the interface.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It is just POC class.

Comment: Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195081/is-a-lambda-expression-something-more-than-an-anonymous-inner-class-with-a-singl answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between single-abstract-method notation and anonymous interface implementations is immaterial, so in my code examples, I will prefer anonymous interface implementations.

Consider these two different ways to provide similar functionality:

**Version 1: Type-level Inheritance**

```
interface Greeter {
    abstract String greet(String name);
}
class MorningGreeter implements Greeter {
    @Override public String greet(String name) {
        return "Good morning, " + name + "!";
    }
}
class EveningGreeter implements Greeter {
    @Override public String greet(String name) {
        return "Good evening, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

**Version 2: Anonymous Implementations**

```
interface Greeter {
    abstract String greet(String name);
    static Greeter morningGreeter = new Greeter() {
        @Override public String greet(String name) {
            return "Good morning, " + name + "!";
        }
    };
    static Greeter eveningGreeter = new Greeter() {
        @Override public String greet(String name) {
            return "Good evening, " + name + "!";
        }
    };
}
```

What are some of the differences? Version 1 adds three type-level abstractions, while Version 2 adds only one. Furthermore, Version 1 allows any number of `MorningGreeter`s and `EveningGreeter`s to be instantiated, whereas Version 2 is written so that there is exactly one `morningGreeter` and exactly one `eveningGreeter`.

I prefer Version 2 for a few reasons.

For one, there's no reason to ever make more than one instance of `MorningGreeter`, since any two instances will function indistinguishably from one another: the only difference will be their memory address. I try to only ever make classes for things that I will instantiate many times and with different properties.

Second, I personally don't think that `MorningGreeter` and `EveningGreeter` should be their own type-level abstractions, since they do not add any methods or fields to `Greeter`. I try to limit my type-level abstractions by the methods and fields they support, since the purpose of the type system is to prevent you from calling the wrong methods on objects that might not support it, and `Greeter` is the type-level abstraction for objects that have a single method with signature `String greet(String name)`. I don't feel there is much value in creating two new type-level abstractions with the exact same methods.

Third, Version 2 presents a clear entry point for users of this (very simple) library. In Version 1, users either need to `grep` all the project files for "implements Greeter" or use IDE magic to jump to the implementing classes. In Version 2, users simply create a greeter with either of the two static convenience methods.

I hope this answers your question. I think it's a good question, more than just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Several objections: 1) the ``abstract`` keyword on the interface method is redundant. 2) subclasses / interface implementations do not need to add methods or fields to have a purpose. They add / implement behaviour, giving them purpose. 3) I think the question is about the difference between lambdas vs. anonymous classes.

Comment: @LarsGendner thanks for the comment. When to subclass and when not to subclass is of course subjective. I simply prefer anonymous implementations in cases like the one above and limit the number type-level abstractions. There are reasons for either approach: I am not seeking to be critical of anyone's coding style. Second, the question specifically asks "Is it better to create anonymous implementors or to create implementing classes?" (paraphrasing) so I'm sure that you can forgive my reading of the question in that respect. Finally, I know `abstract` is redundant there ;-p Cheers :-)

Comment: I think our discussion about what the questioner means is a hint that the question is not clear ;-)